# angular ng-repeat not rendering <li>

Tags: javascript, angularjs

for some reason, this code below is not rendering the items in my tabs array. This is angular 101, I know, but for the life of me, only five "next:" values are showing, but not the {{item}}. any idea why? Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
  <head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script>

  function navCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.tabs = ['DASH', 'TRACK', 'MAP', 'TRENDS', 'ADMIN']
  }

  </script>
  </head>

  <body>
 <div ng-controller='navCtrl'>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in tabs">next: {{ item }}</li>
  </ul>
</div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/byqnu853/

Comment: This is the running plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/G2EW0xPwMi6L58NJD12F?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

`<li ng-repeat="item in tabs">next: <span ng-bind="item"> </span></li>`